# Devise 3.2 + Rspec 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I'm trying to build some tests with Rspec and I'm getting the following error:

```
     Failure/Error: get :index
     NoMethodError:
     undefined method `authenticate!' for nil:NilClass
```

Then I made some searchs and I realized that I had to include this line in the spec_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
end
```

It seems that this code worked for most people but not for me. Now i'm getting the following error:

```
/home/bruna/Dropbox/Rails/academico/spec/spec_helper.rb:18:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Devise (NameError)
```

I think this might be some error in this version of rspec and/or devise. Has anyone seen this error? Please, help me :'(

Comment: how did you install Devise?

Comment: Both devise and rspec are listed in my gemfile.

Comment: are you using Devise anywhere else in your app without problems?

Comment: Yes, I do everything, I just can't test with rspec.

Answer (score -2):

RSpec 3 configuration is different from earlier versions, with the addition of a *spec/rails_helper.rb* file that must be included for each spec file. Add the Devise TestHelpers to the *spec/rails_helper.rb* file.

If you need more information about RSpec 3 configuration, I've written an [RSpec Tutorial](http://railsapps.github.io/rspec.html). There's also information about testing Devise with RSpec, including advice about session helpers for feature testing, in my [Rails Devise Tutorial](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-devise/).

Comment: I've already added Devise TestHelpers to the spec/rails_helper and I get the error uninitialized constant Devise (NameError), like I said upstairs